# Matching \[\] in Python regexes

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace all expressions of the form

```
\[something\]
```

in a string by

```
\[<img src='something'>\]
```

Since `\` and `[` `]` are special characters, I need to espace them (so `\\`, `\[` and `\]`), thus my code would be

```
def repl(m):
    return "<img src='"+m.group(1)+"'>"

print re.sub("\\\[(.*?)\\\]", repl, "frfrfr\nfrrffr<p>\[something\]</p>frff\nfrfrr", re.S)
```

However, this returns the original string. Could someone point out my mistake ?

Comment: You have it almost right: But you must use raw strings to ensure that the regexp engine sees exactly what you typed. `r"\\\[..."`. Raw strings are _always_ a good habit with regexps (even if in some cases you could do without them.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape `\` correctly, or use `r'raw string'` as follow.

```
>>> print re.sub(r"\\\[(.*?)\\\]", repl, "frfrfr\nfrrffr<p>\[something\]</p>frff\nfrfrr", flags=re.S)
frfrfr
frrffr<p><img src='something'></p>frff
frfrr

>>> print re.sub("\\\\\\[(.*?)\\\\\\]", repl, "frfrfr\nfrrffr<p>\[something\]</p>frff\nfrfrr", flags=re.S)
frfrfr
frrffr<p><img src='something'></p>frff
frfrr
```

**UPDATE**

The fourth parameter of [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is `count`, not `flags`. To specify flags, use keyword arguments. Otherwise, `re.S` is recognized as `count`.

```
>>> print re.sub(r"\\\[(.*?)\\\]", repl, "frfrfr\nfrrffr<p>\[something\nblah\]</p>frff\nfrfrr", re.S)
frfrfr
frrffr<p>\[something
blah\]</p>frff
frfrr
>>> print re.sub(r"\\\[(.*?)\\\]", repl, "frfrfr\nfrrffr<p>\[something\nblah\]</p>frff\nfrfrr", flags=re.S)
frfrfr
frrffr<p><img src='something
blah'></p>frff
frfrr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I still have a small issue, maybe you have an idea: do you know why it doesn't matches something like ` "<p>\[something\nblah\]</p>"` (i.e. newline inside the group) ?

Comment: @Klaus, I udpate the answer with regard to `flags` parameter. Check it out.